# Extending $G$-closed sets to permutation bases of a permutation $RG$-module

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, modules

I'm curious if there are any papers or results about the following scenario:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring (I'm interested in particular in the $R = \mathbb{Z}$ case, but fields are okay too), $G$ a finite group, and $M$ be a finitely generated permutation $RG$-module. Suppose
> $\mathcal{B}$ is a set of $R$-linearly independent elements of $M$
> which is closed under $G$-multiplication. What properties must be satisfied by $\mathcal{B}$ for $\mathcal{B}$ to be extendable to a *permutation* basis of $M$?

I have some specific cases for when I know a set of this form can be extended to a full permutation basis, and there are plenty of counterexamples one can cook up where a set cannot be extended, but I'm wondering if this has been studied in greater detail. I wasn't able to find anything on a first pass, but this seems like something that likely has been studied before, and such results would help me extend some results to much greater generality!

I wonder as well if there are any analogous results for, in the case where $R$ is a finite field, $p$-permutation modules, i.e. considering $M$ as a permutation $RP$-module for some Sylow $p$-subgroup $P\leq G$.